# Faster query with 2d shape over 10.000.000 records mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, 2d, box

I have a product schema

```
 {
    type:ObjectId,
    point: { type:"Point", coordinates:Array},
    category_id:ObjectId,
    price:Number
 }
```

I want to query with filter type, point, category_id, price, point like:

```
Product.find({
    type_id:{$in:[ObjectId("5d679819325ab70ab0157ce5"),...]}, 
    category_id:{$in:[ObjectId("5d679819325ab70ab0157ce5"),...],}
    price:{$gte:30},
    point: {
      $geoWithin: {
         $box:boxInput: //like [ [ 10.479445601358, 10.479445601358 ], [ 105.67003470372651, 105.67003470372651] ]
      }
  }
})
```

the boxInput with change with any query and the question is how can I create indexes with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add as many indexes as are necessary. Note that your sample schema has `type` but your query has `type_id`; beware of silent non-matches due to key name errors.   Probably no reason to put an index on `price`.

```
printjson ( db.foo.createIndex({point:"2dsphere"})  );
printjson ( db.foo.createIndex({type:1})  );
printjson ( db.foo.createIndex({category_id:1})  );
```